# Can't link to election comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks, election

I wanted to put a link to one of the comments on [this election page](https://superuser.com/election/3) into chat. But it seems that isn't supported, for some reason. Normally you can just click the "x hours ago" link on a comment, and that takes you straight to it and lets you link to it. But on the election page there's no link, just straight text.

I'm guessing this is intentional, because it would be a really weird bug, but I'm wondering 1) why this is the case and 2) if there isn't a really compelling reason, can we change it? I'd like to be able to discuss nominations with people and point out specific comments, just like I would with any other post.

Comment: Well, using dev tools of the browser you can get the comment id then have [such link](http://superuser.com/election/3#comment-958915) but it won't be oneboxed in chat. :(